# Wordpress WPSC quick ask

Tags: wordpress

I'm querying through wpsc_start_category_query and then I want to get only one product from quered product.

like:
      query category
       category1
      query product by category1
       product1
      query category
       category2
      query product by category2
      and etc..

```
 <?php wpsc_start_category_query(array('category_group'=> get_option('wpsc_default_category'), 'show_thumbnails'=> 1)); ?>
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'orderby' => 'rand',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'wpsc_product_category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => 'HERESOMECODE'
                        )
                            )
                    );
 $cat1_posts = get_posts($args);
 ?>
```

my problem is that I can't give 'wpsc_product_category' => wpsc_category_name();
I mean I cant query one post for current category

any sugestions?
really easy task and I really broke my brain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to query posts in WP E-commerce plugin query as they differ in structure and WPSC is limited its functions.

I've done it by using WordPress built-in query.

```
//for each category, show latest post
$cat_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
   );
$categories = get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category');
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'orderby' => 'ID',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'showposts' => 1,
      'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
      'wpsc_product_category' => $category->slug
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
            foreach($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post); 
          $date1 = get_the_time('U', $post->ID);
       }
        // post details goes here 
      } 
    } 
?>
```

the thing I've done here, started first category query and in category query I queried posts.

Of course it a little bit expansive query but If you have less then 100 posts in 6 categories it works perfect.